# Can I install Ubuntu Touch on an Android phone with an MTK6735 quad core 64-bit CPU?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, touchscreen

I don't see a recognizable brand name anywhere. All it says on the box is "4GVoLTE" I notice that the list of officially supported phones is rather short. However, a quick search finds quite a few brands of phones that use this CPU chip, so I was hoping there might be something that would work. This is a dual-sim phone. Here is the rest of the information on the "About" page:

- Model number: 4G
- Android version: 4.4.2
- Baseband version: MTK6735
- Kernel version: 3.0.8
  daiweiping@user#1
- Hardware version: A12E_V1.0

While full functionality  would be great, all I really need for this project is wifi, web browser and touchscreen display.

Comment: Unless someone has ported it (which I doubt) you're out of luck unless you are able to port it yourself.

Comment: It's most likely an ARM processor with the same instruction set as a Snapdragon family chip.  The issue is likely to be, without any technical documentation, how to either boot to Ubuntu Touch on microSD, or how to flash Ubuntu Touch into the phone's ROM.